# Is this a right way to say you jumped on someone to pin them to the ground in combat?

Tags: phrase-usage

"I threw/flung myself at him and locked him"

Comment: Regarding your title, note that combat is normally treated as uncountable, so you would say "in combat" not "in **a** combat".

Comment: "pin them to the group"?  Do you mean "pin them to the ground"?

Comment: Got it @JavaLatte. Yeah, I meant "to the ground" stangdon. It got autocorrected and I missed it. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of the sentence, "**I threw/flung myself at him**", is grammatically correct, and works in the sentence. However, the second section "locked him", is a bit awkward, as "**locked him**" without giving a location seems awkward. You may want to try "locked him in my arms", or simply "locked him in." *The important part is the preposition.*

Comment: Is it just awkward or plainly wrong?

Comment: "Locked him" is not a commonly used idiom, so it is technically incorrect.